# How to make Dutch auction system price decrement every second

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am developing an app with a Dutch-style auction.

In a Dutch-style auction, the prices drop gradually UNTIL someone accepts the bid, and if nobody accepts the bid before a preset (low) threshold is reached, the price resets to its initial high value, over and over again.

I don't know how to broadcast the new prices from the server side.

eg: the product's price is 1000, every second, it should down 10 and broadcast to all users. i can't found a good way to do this. I've tried this:

```
 price = 1000
  while price > 0
      price = price - 10
      // broadcast to all users
      sleep 1
    end
  end
```

But it not work.

Comment: Your subject is really misleading. What you want to solve is how to have real-time notifications from the server to the clients (browsers). You should look into websockets. It is possible to integrate that in Ruby on Rails.

Comment: @babgyy Sorry for my weak english. eg: the product's price is 1000, every second, it should down 10 and broadcast to all users. i can't found a good way to do this.

Comment: No worries, I was just saying that your question could me more specific about your needs. You definitely need to learn about websockets. Wikipedia will help. In a basic web application (using HTTP protocol), the client (your browser) requests the server once to get the content of a page, displays the page to the user and then waits for user action. There was no way for the server to "broadcast" to every client. That is why you need another protocol to enable your client to "subscribe" to messages from the server: websocket is one such protocol.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology

Comment: Yes, i used rails 5 and action cable, but i don't know how to make the price down 10 every second from 1000 to 0.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [eventmachine](https://github.com/eventmachine/eventmachine) [periodic timer](http://www.rubydoc.info/github/eventmachine/eventmachine/EventMachine/PeriodicTimer) and try something like this.

```
price = 1000
timer = EventMachine::PeriodicTimer.new(1) do 

  #broadcast the current price with action cable to users here
  #send_message
  price -= 10   
  if (price) < 10
    price = 1000
  end
end
```

Replace the `#send_message` comment by the actual broadcast with action cable.

Comment: I tested this, but when a user open browser, this will run one time, if there are 10 users, this will run 10 times.

Comment: Where did you put it ?
It should not be in a controller method that all users will call. Either in a controller method that only the admin will call when starting the auction, or in a background job that will trigger under certain circonstances.

Comment: I want to make it auto start when the auction time start，i can't find a way to do it in sidekiq.

Comment: Where are you stuck ? Can you show what you did so far ?

Comment: I haven't got a good way to do this, still haven't idea to make price down every second. It seems to should use background job.

Comment: That's where sidekiq kicks in indeed. But you should try to read the documentation, and then edit your post to highlight where you're stuck